# Redux & React: componentDidUpdate is called but rerendering doesn't happen

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am loading data from Rest API, Container and Presentational components take it.

**Container**

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.load();
  }

componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log('updated');
}

render() {
  let view;

  view = this.props.data ? (<Foo data={this.props.data} />) : (<H2>Loading</H2>)

  return (
    <div>
      {view}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`load` - fetches data and dispatched event in reducer on success load.

**@Connect**

```
function select(state) {
  const { data } = state.modules;

  return {
    data: data
  };
}

export default connect(select, {
  load: actions.data.load
})(ContainerComponent);
```

As far as I understand, when action is dispatched and `Container` component receives updated data from store, rerender should happen.

Which is strange, `componentDidUpdate`, according to the docs, is called when component received updated props and rerendered.

But my `Foo` (dumb) component never shows up even though everything is successfully dispatched without state mutation.

What could be the cause? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the part of your code where you implement `mapStateToProps` and `connect` the component with the redux store?

Comment: @Timo updated question

Comment: Maybe this.props.data is always false? Could you post a more complete code?

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your code maybe a fiddle? everything looks ok here, but I want to see how the connect is used with the containercomponent more IE how you are exporting it

Comment: Your component will only re-render if the props passed in `connect` have changed. Can you post your reducer code, as it looks like this is not updating the state?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reasons for a component not to re-render is that you modify the state instead of returning a copy of the state with changes applied.

This is mentioned in the [Troubleshooting](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html) part of the Redux docs.

Comment: Thanks, I did a lot of googling before going here, read this article already, my state is not mutated

Comment: @knitevision ok good, just a guess :) Good to hear that you googled a lot before asking, a lot of people don't.

Answer (score 0):

As @kjonsson was hinting, the issue is that you directly assign `state.modules.data` to the `data` property on the *select object*. The reference of that data object never changes and thus the component will never re-render. What you have to do is **copying** `state.modules.data` using the spread operator, such that whenever `state.modules.data` changes the `data` field on the *select object* will have a new reference.

Below the adjusted code snippet.

```
function select(state) {
  const { data } = state.modules;

  return {
    data: { ...data }
  };
}

export default connect(select, {
  load: actions.data.load
})(ContainerComponent);
```

Please let me know if this helps!